# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 - Changed IP, but DNS Server still pointing to old IP

Tags: dns, netplan, ip

I have a Ubuntu 22.04.2 server that I setup with a static IP and joined to a Windows Domain. The IP was configured on /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml and /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.

[image]

From other devices I could ping the hostname, and it resolved the IP address correctly.

Now I changed the servers IP (01-netcfg.yaml and 00-installer-config.yaml), restarted, but if I ping from other devices on the network it returns the old IP.

What do I have to change to get the DNS to resolve the proper IP?

Comment: You will need to update the DNS record on your DNS server for the server to reflect the new IP address

Comment: Shouldnt this happen automatically?  For other Windows Servers, it does it automatically.  Granted I understand, totally different systems.